# How to hide current element and show next on button click?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, opera-mini

I have a JQuery questionnaire website on mobile. Most of the website users use Opera Mini, and the current JQuery mobile animations are not fully supported.

I then decided to implement a bootstrap based website, rather than JQuery mobile. This time I want to implement so that one question appears at a time,  and when a user wants to go to the next question, they just press next.

How can I implement this?

I currently have something like this:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('#question1').hide();
    $('#question2').show();

});
```

But I have 30 some-odd questions, so, how can I set it up dynamically with as simple of a code as possible?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you shouldnt use `id`s for something like this, it's just more trouble than it's worth. Instead, just use classes. A simple implementation might look like this:

```js
$('#next').click(function(){
    var $current = $('.question.active');
    // use $current here to test if the question was answered if needed 
    // maybe something like if($current.find('.answer').val().trim() == ''){ return;}
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.next().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.question:not(.active){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="questions">
  <div class="question active">Some question 1</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 2</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 3</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 4</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 5</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 6</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 7</div>
  <div class="question">Some question 8</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: it Works well, but the problem is that it does not allow me to add all the answers to the database, it only adds the first response. How can I solve that issue, because I want to add all the responses to the database. @DelightedD0D

Comment: @neliza you'll have to be way more specific. Why does this "not allow you to add all the answers to the database"? How are you doing that exactly? You can certainly still get all the answers the user entered, but I you dont show any of that.

Comment: Your input is  indeed helpful sir. What I mean by "not allow you to add all the answers to the database" is that only the first response of the first question gets inserted into the database. When I press next it goes straight to the php script that processes the form, and inserts the first response correctly the other responses become zero in the database. How can i code it such that the responses get inserted after all the questions have been answered.

Comment: @neliza can you ask a new question and provide the code there that actually sends the data to the backend? Add a link to it here and Ill take a look, we'll get you sorted ;)

Comment: Ahhh, I bet you have your button inside a form element and it's submitting the form when you hit the button. Make that other question so we can get a look to verify, or add the code here

Comment: @neliza actually, just update the button to `<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>` and see if that doesnt solve your issue ;)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that hiding the questions via CSS is a bad idea. Users with JavaScript disabled will never get to see the hidden questions. Instead, you could do it with jQuery: `$(".question:not(.active)").hide();`

Comment: @natejms not really man. "users with javascript disabled" hasnt real been a problem since about the time My Space died. Currently, these users make up about [**0.2%** of web users](https://blockmetry.com/blog/javascript-disabled) and over 10% of those users are Tor users doing so for privacy reasons (not users that are likely to be visiting the OP's questionnaire app.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Fair point, but never the less. I'm sure not too many of the OP's visitors are using NoScript or anything, but it's still something to keep in mind. For future readers, if not them.

Answer (score 0):

Basically each JavaScript interaction in Opera Mini requires a round-trip -
 when a user clicks "Next", it's browser sends a click event to Opera Mini servers. The JavaScript is executed on those servers and rendered page is sent back to client. Definitely a waste of time!

Users will definitely appreciate if they can simply answer all questions at once and then send a complete form.

Answer (score -1):

If we're to use jQuery as in the example you gave in the question, the program could look something along the lines of the following.

It looks like you are wrapping each element in an element that has the ID of "question", followed by the question number. If each question follows this rule, we can declare a variable and give it a value of one (we'll call this variable `q`). To select the current question, use `$("#question" + q)`. Each time the `#next` button is clicked, hide the current question, add 1 to `q` and open the next. For an example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#">
  <div id="question1" class="questions">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Question 1">
  </div>
  <div id="question2" class="questions">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Question 2">
  </div>
  <div id="question3" class="questions">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Question 3">
  </div>
  <div id="question4" class="questions">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Question 4">
  </div>
  <div id="question5" class="questions">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Question 5">
  </div>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</form>

<script>
  var q = 1

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".questions").hide();
    $("#question1").show();
  
    $("#next").click(function() {
    
      $("#question" + q).hide();
       q = q + 1;
      if(q > 5) {
        $("#next").remove();
        $("body").append("<input type='submit' value='Submit'>");
      } else {
        $("#question" + q).show();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here, each time you click the `#next` button, one digit gets added to the `q` variable. If all 5 questions have been passed, the submit button appears, thus allowing you to submit your answers. Otherwise, the next question gets displayed.

If you wanted to add any animations, you could simply swap out `.hide()` and `.show()` with things like `.fadeIn()`, `.slideDown()`, etc cetera.

### Edit - Back button

If we're using classes instead of ID's as done by @DelightedD0D (since it is infact more manageble), you could create a back button buy using the `.prev()` method in order to select the previous element.

```
$('#previous').click(function(){
    var $current = $('.question.active');
    $('.question').removeClass('active');
    $current.prev().addClass('active');
});
```

If you're using ID's, it would look something like this:

```
$("#previous").click(function() {
    if((q - 1) == 1) {
      $("#previous").hide();
    }
    $("#question" + q).hide();
    q = q - 1;
    $("#question" + q).show();

});
```

With the following modifications to the rest of the script:

```
$(".questions").hide();
$("#previous").hide();
$("#question1").show();

$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#question" + q).hide();
    q = q + 1;
    if(!$("#previous").is(":visible")) {
      $("#previous").show();
    }
    if(q > 5) {
      $("#next,#previous").remove();
      $("body").append("<input type='submit' value='Submit'>");
    } else {
      $("#question" + q).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I like your code, thank you for taking your precious time to help in with the code @natejms, since there is a next button, is it possible to have a previous button? How can that be implemented sir?

Comment: @neliza Anytime! I edited my post to include the additional information.